# Проблема подключения бота на сервер в discord

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-api

Всем привет, я столкнулся с проблемой подключения бота discord на сервер, подскажите пожалуйста, что такое **REDIRECT URL**, где его взять?

Если мне не изменяет память, то раньше этого не было

Заранее спасибо за помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Уберите чек в этом пункте (Во вкладке Bot)
[image: Ytn]

Comment: Какой пункт, какая вкладка? Опишите весь процесс и что это даст в итоге.

Comment: Тогда не нужно будет вводить redirected url, я уже написал что этот чек во вкладке Bot